# Parsing JSON without having to define "data" class

Tags: json, haskell

I have a bunch of such the requests to the servers which returns JSON:

```
MyJsonData = MyJsonData { field1 :: String, field2 :: String }
d <- (Aeson.eitherDecode <$> simpleHttp "https://someUrl.com") :: IO (Either String MyJsonData)
print d

MyJsonData2 = MyJsonData2 { field12 :: String, field22 :: String }
d2 <- (Aeson.eitherDecode <$> simpleHttp "https://someUrl2.com") :: IO (Either String MyJsonData2)
print d2
```

Of course, all the servers return similar but not exact data in terms of the JSON representation. I need to obtain the values only from only a few of these fields, I don't need them all. I'd like to be able to do something like the following:

```
-- not valid Haskell code!
(d1, d2) <- (Aeson.eitherDecode <$> simpleHttp "https://someUrl.com") :: IO (Either String (_ _ _ fieldINeed _ _ fieldIneed2))
print d1
print d2

(d3, d4) <- (Aeson.eitherDecode <$> simpleHttp "https://someUrl2.com") :: IO (Either String (_ _ fieldINeed3 fieldIneed4 _ _ _))
print d3
print d4
```

Or something similar. The idea is get rid of necessity to define `data`S `MyJsonData`, `MyJsonData2` and so on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
output <- Aeson.eitherDecode rawData :: IO (Either String Aeson.Value)
case output of
    Right jsonValue -> case jsonValue of
        (Aeson.Object jsonObject) -> case (HashMap.lookup "someKey" jsonObject, HashMap.lookup "anotherKey" jsonObject) of
             (Just val, Just val2) -> -- Your code here
             _ -> error "Couldn't get both keys"
        _ -> error "Unexpected JSON"
    Left errorMsg -> error $ "Error in parsing: " ++ errorMsg
```

Basically, a JSON object is just a [HashMap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.1.2.0/docs/Data-HashMap-Lazy.html) that you can manipulate and a JSON array is just a [vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.9.1/docs/Data-Vector.html#t%3aVector).

If you have a bunch of keys you can just `map` the `HashMap.lookup` over an array of keys and then run a `sequence` on the list to get what you want.

```
case (sequence $ map (\k -> HashMap.lookup k jsonObject) ["key1", "key2", "key3"]) of
    Just x -> -- Your code here
    Nothing -> error "Some key missing"
```

Comment: `Not in scope: `Data.HashMap.Lazy.lookup'`

Comment: although in .cabal I added `hashmap,
    containers,
    unordered-containers,
    http-types`

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Data.Aeson.Value` is instance of `FromJSON`. So you can decode response to `Value` and then extract only what you need.

For example

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Control.Monad

parser1 :: Value -> Parser (String, String)
parser1 (Object o) = do
  str1 <- o .: "str1"
  str2 <- o .: "str2"
  return (str1, str2)
parser1 _ = mzero

parser2 :: Value -> Parser (String, String)
parser2 (Object o) = do
  str1 <- o .: "string1"
  str2 <- o .: "string2"
  return (str1, str2)    
parser2 _ = mzero

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let json1 = object [
        "str1" .= ("world" :: String),
        "str2" .= ("12" :: String),
        "other" .= (12.5 :: Float)
        ]
  let json2 = object [
        "string1" .= ("world" :: String),
        "string2" .= ("12" :: String),
        "other" .= (12.5 :: Float)
        ]
  print $ parseEither parser1 json1
  print $ parseEither parser2 json2
```

ADD:
You can parameterize parser with field names:

```
parser :: (Text, Text) -> Value -> Parser (String, String)
parser (f1, f2) (Object o) = do
  str1 <- o .: f1
  str2 <- o .: f2
  return (str1, str2)
parser _ _ = mzero
...
print $ parseEither (parser ("str1", "str2")) json1
print $ parseEither (parser ("string1", "string2")) json2
```

Comment: You just replaced MyJsonData with parser1, MyJsonData2 with parser2, but how is this beneficial?

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are asking for. Didn't you asked how to "get rid of necessity to define data's"?

Comment: Yes, I did. And this implies the necessity to define any other types or functions for each particular function doing a request to the server. I'd like to have one data type or function, not many. You got rid of data but you brought parse1, parse2 instead. In terms of the amount of code, isn't that the same?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp You need to specify how to find you data in json. Note that both parsers are almost identical, so you can abstract it a bit more.